# How can I stop the form submit when I input wrong type info in the form using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
function validation() {
var isNameValid = checkName();
var isEmailValid = checkEmail();
var isCorrectPassword = checkPassword();
var isSame = checkSame();

// Check if they are all true -> return true
    // Else return false
if (isNameValid && isEmailValid && isSame && isCorrectPassword) {

    return true;

   } 
   else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

This is function for validation, just didn't put all the sub functions here, they're all doing the same thing: check if input is empty and show error message in span tag and return false if there's a error.
I call this validation function from "onclick" of the form's submit button
But the form still can be submitted even the passwords are different and returned false, how can I fix this
Thank you for any advice.

Comment: I believe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-to-stop-form-submission answers your question

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this validation function is being called in the form's submit event - this is important. Simply prevent the default action:

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(event){
  return isValidForm();
});

function isValidForm(){
  var isNameValid = checkName();
  var isEmailValid = checkEmail();
  var isCorrectPassword = checkPassword();
  var isSame = checkSame();

  // Check if they are all true -> return true
  // Else return false
  if (isNameValid && isEmailValid && isSame && isCorrectPassword) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call the function on `onsubmit` instead of `onclick`